# How can I regain access to my Minecraft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so i changed my name a little while a ago. About a week; and i just want to play minecraft so i open up the launcher log out then back in for my account to update but it says the username or password is incorrect so i tried again and again. still didn't work! then i went onto the minecraft website tried to log in it didnt work. note that i didn't change my password or email just my Minecraft IGN so then after almost an hour of trying to get it, i just changed my email to see if that would work... but still nope! at that point i gave up and posted here.

How can I regain access to my account?

Comment: How did you change your email without being able to log in? As your account is migrated, make sure you are using your email address to log in, and not your username. Have you tried the forgot password link?

Comment: i changed my email i forgot how but i did. And i was using my email address to log in. i've tried the forgot password link multiple times already.

Comment: And what happens when you try it?

Comment: it just keeps saying that my username or password is incorrect

Comment: You don't need your password to reset your password (that'd make it a fairly pointless recovery feature), just your email. Go to [this page](https://account.mojang.com/password), enter the email associated with the account, and see what happens.

Comment: This still isn't working, i changed my password but its still saying that it is incorrect. i type in my email address and password but no not working at all....

Comment: Sure you're typing in the exact same password as what you changed it to, and using the exact same email address as the email that the password reset request was sent to? May be worth copying and pasting both to make sure. Also watch out for things like dots in your email name or the difference between `@gmail.com` and `@googlemail.com`.

Comment: And i use @gmail.com . Sadly no it is still not working.... i might have to get a new account...

Comment: Could try to contact Mojang support, or [try to change your email again](https://account.mojang.com/changeemail/request).

Answer (score 2):

Go to help.mojang.net and contact Mojang support. Let them know of the issue, they'll be able to see what's wrong from the inside, and with proof that you own the account (your transaction ID of buying minecraft would be best), they can change the password and email for you to make it so you can log in with the new password or email. If that doesn't work, keep in touch with the support team so they can help you figure out the issue. After you've done all this, come back here and let us know if it fixed it for you.

Hope this helps you fix your problem!